# Has the next particle accelerator been designed yet?

Tags: experimental-physics, particle-accelerators

Has the next particle accelerator been designed yet? As I understand it is called the Future Circular Collider. Where are we at in the process of this?

Comment: Conceptual design, preliminary design, final design. Fantasy design? Lots of steps in a design process most of which happen when it gets funded...

Comment: In addition to what @Jon said, there isn't **a** next particle acceleration. Because there isn't one goal in particle physics and rarely only one way to get to the goal you pick. So there are always conceptual designs floating around looking for money and there are often several proposed projects chasing any pool of money that is expected. Currently on the horizon (that I'm aware of): the ILC and a couple of electron-ion collider designs. A muon collider is still a bit blue sky but people start to droll when its brought up.

Comment: @dmckee What would be the point of the ILC if it only powers up to 3 TEV? Don’t we know we won’t see anything since the LHC runs at 14 TEV?

Comment: @Nov - the ILC is colliding electrons and positrons. Totally different physics from protons.

Comment: @JonCuster could we possibly detect SUSY with it?

Comment: @Nov For a historical parallel, compare the records of SLAC and LEP/LEP II with those of high-energy hadron machines running at the same time. The rule of thumb we give to  particle physics students is hadrons at higher energies and luminosity lead to discoveries, but leptons yield much higher precision measurements (especially of fundamental interaction constants). EIC type schemes are intended for high precision measurements of nucleon and nuclear parameters. Like I said above, there is more than one goal in particle physics no matter how pop-sci source focus on just highest energies.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, apart from the FCC there is two other options respectively rival projects on the table. These are a high-energy upgrade of the LHC (CMS energy 27TeV instead of 14TeV called HE-LHC) and the Chinese CEPC (Chinese electron positron collider, circumference ~100km) which aims in a first step at an CMS energy $e^+e^-$ of 240GeV (being a Higgsfactory based on the  $e^+e^-\rightarrow Zh$ process), but which is meant to be later upgraded to a hadron machine.

Actually all 3 possibilities have at least their Conceptual Design Report (CDR) at least partly ready, the CDR of CERN is aimed to be fully accomplished by the end of 2018 for both options FCC and HE-LHC. Large parts of the CDRs can already be consulted on the internet: http://cepc.ihep.ac.cn for the CEPC and https://readthedocs.web.cern.ch/display/SUS/FCC+CDR for CERN, but the access is password protected.